# How to load a specific xml based on the profile set in the environment in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Let's say I have XML files in my project such as `a.xml`, `b.xml`, `c.xml`

Now I want to load a specific XML based on the profile set in `spring boot`.
**E.g** - If the profile is test1 then I want to load `a.xml`,
____ If the profile is test2 then I want to load `b.xml` and so on.

How to achieve this using Spring boot. Any Help would be really appreciated. I am new to this. So I could not find any appropriate solution for this.

Comment: is it only for tests you want to use different xml configs?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, your configuration xml should define what profile it defines beans for.

second, all of them should already be loaded, spring wont use the definitions that are specific to an unactivated profile

```xml
file a.xml:
<beans profile="test1">
 ... your bean definitions that only get activated on profile test1 here
</beans>
file b.xml:
<beans profile="test2">
 ... your bean definitions that only get activated on profile test2 here
</beans>
```

now all your xml files define what configuration the run on you can startup the whole application with all the config files.

and the magic: you can change the profile in any way spring boot provides, be it a enviroment var, a programatoric way, an argument on startup.... the ways are endless

see [profile documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) for information about this
or [baeldung tutorial about profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)

after startup only the beans of activated profiles will be there, those of the xml's with a unactivated profile will not exist (I guess/think the config will still be loaded, only no instances will be created for them)